# How to iterate through a list to group data via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with several properties and two lists on which I want to filter the data.

```
public class data {
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public List<Enumeration1> Categories {get; set;}
    public List<Enumeration2> Groups {get; set;}
```

In the List "Categories", I am searching for an entry. So selecting is easy. But in the second List, I want to iterate through and adding the element to every output group the statement is generating.

The result of this query should be added to a grouped by all the keys in the second list.

Grouping by the first key in the Groups list is what I already have.

```
var groupedElements = from elem in Source.Elements 
  where elem.CategoryList.Contains(cat) 
  group elem by elem.GroupList.FirstOrDefault() into newGroup 
  orderby newGroup.Key 
  select newGroup;
```

An alternative solution I already have implemented is manually grouping in a dictionary:

```
var selectedCategory = from elem in Source.Elements where elem.Categories.Contains(cat) select elem;
Dictionary<Enumeration2, List<Element>> groupedElements = new();
foreach (var elem in selectedCategory)
{
    foreach (var group in elem.Groups)
    {
        if (!groupedElements.ContainsKey(group))
            groupedElements.Add(group, new List<Element>());
        groupedElements[group].Add(param);
    }
}
```

So my question is how to set the LINQstatement that the result is like it is solved in the alternative solution?

Comment: Can't be done in one LINQ statement, stick to the solution you have.

Comment: This is a side-effecting loop. The Q of LINQ is for _Query_, don't use LINQ for side-effecting operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `param` came from but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
var groupedElements = (from elem in Source.Elements
                       where elem.Categories.Contains(cat)
                       from grp in elem.Groups
                       group elem by grp into g
                       select g).ToDictionary(static item => item.Key, static item => item.ToList());
```